# Assign symbology to multiple layers in one operation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.0, symbology

Is it possible to assign the same symbol to multiple layers of the same geometry type within an ArcMap document in one operation?

For example, I was hoping to:

1. Select multiple layers in the TOC
2. Click on the symbol "patch" or right-click an get to the "Symbol Selector".
3. Apply the same symbol to all selected layers.

Obviously that doesn't work, or I wouldn't be asking.  I found an old 2003 posting that talks about [how to do this with VBA code](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=98877).  Can this type of operation be done from the GUI in 10.x, or am I just out of luck?